Should an equipment closet have both supply and return vents for cooling?
I have a closet about 3' by 8'. I want to put computer equipment inside.  Can I put an intake and an outtake opening for the A/C in the closet?  This is to make sure the area does not overheat.

Is the A/C always an air conditioner, or is it a heater for part of the year? Are there days or weeks of the year when the weather is mild and the A/C (or heat) runs little or not at all?
If the A/C is not dedicated to the closet, or at least does not have a thermostat in the closet that can cause the system to run as needed based on heating in the closet, then you may be going to a lot of trouble building a solution that won't reliably solve the problem.
If the A/C sometimes runs as a heater then definitely don't run supply ducts into the closet. Connect a return duct instead. If possible, put the return duct near the ceiling and provide a way for adjacent-room air to enter the closet down low.
How much heat are we talking about? If the computer equipment actual power consumption will be approaching 10 amps at 120 volts (1200 Watts/hr, or 4100 Btu/hr) then you might be well-advised to install a 9000 Btu/hr mini-split air conditioner to provide dedicated cooling for the closet.
Before going to the trouble of running duct work any distance, I'd consider whether louvers high and low, possibly with a fan to force air through, could exchange air with adjacent room(s) and deal with the heat well enough.

If there's significant heat, then it should be ducted outside during cooling season and to the rest of the house in heating season. You already paid for the electricity to make the heat, might as well use it to help heat the house when needed.

I would do one or the other and supplement that with a louver in the door.
If you put in a small service duct a louver will allow the air out. Best is service in at the bottom and out at the top. The hot air rising will get pushed out the top louver.
If you do a return do the opposite.  Return pulls air from near the top and is replaced with cooler air from outside the closet near the bottom.
My concern with supply and return both in a closet is the air will be piped in and sucked out without much of any time to transfer heat from the equipment.

I generally agree, but your last statement is faulty. Time reduces efficiency, as heat transfer is a function of temperature differential. The same argument comes up on automotive forums with respect to coolant circulation. It's flawed thinking. Flow rate is beneficial, at least to the point of severe turbulence. We're not flying jets, though. :)

I think that just a return vent is appropriate. Here's why:

A supply vent moves more air than a return vent, typically. This means positive pressure in the room, which will push heated air into the adjacent spaces. You don't want that.

A return pulls heated air into the HVAC system for conditioning. It prevents most leakage into the adjacent spaces.

Makeup air in the closet pulls from the adjacent space (though door gaps). Since this is conditioned, it serves to cool the equipment. Most interior doors are far from sealed, so I don't consider a louver necessary.

You can run the system with fan only between cooling cycles, so that the closet is still being evacuated (full time, if you like).


Now if you have a severe heat issue you may want both supply and return vents in the closet, but you'll want to seal the room. This will improve efficiency and prevent the aforementioned leakage to adjacent spaces.
Ultimately this depends on the nuances of your equipment needs, your local climate, your heating and cooling preferences, and the HVAC system itself. You may want to take a staged approach to see what works.
